# Why reduced atoms are more energetic?

Tags: redox

For example, in glycolysis, $\ce{NAD+} $ is reduced to $\ce{NADH}$ and then it's more energetic. Why adding electrons to an atoms gives it more energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All electrochemistry is relative.  And any time you have a reduction or oxidation reaction, you are dealing with an electrochemistry problem.

NADH is "more energetic" than NAD+ because the hidden assumption is that energy levels are *relative* to reaction with the atmosphere.  NADH can react with oxygen in the atmosphere to release energy.  But on a planet with no oxygen and lots of hydrogen in the atmosphere, NAD+ would be the "more energetic" molecule.

Another less exotic example is anaerobic fermentation in yeast.  NADH builds up in glycolysis, and must be converted back to NAD+ through formation of ethanol + CO2.  That process consumes energy; thus, in anaerobic environments, often times NAD+ can be thought of as a higher-energy molecule than NADH.

Answer (score 0):

Energy of polyelectronic atoms is hard to calculate since you have to take care of the individual energy of each electrons bu also of interaction between them.

To simplify, you can assume the addition of an electron will bring the energy of the electron plus maybe some other interaction wich will rise the total energy of the atom.

Answer (score 0):

NADH is more energetic because it holds more bonds, therefore more energy is required to keep this molecule intact. So when trying to break the bond, it would require more energy to break, and therefore it is also more stable then NAD+. NAD+ is energetically unfavorable because it is a cation. Adding a hydrogen will give it favorability, but it will also hold the molecule with more energy.